# getting 'net err cache miss' message

Tags: php, samsung-mobile

I have a PHP script that sends an html email to the user that contains a form with some results info along with an HTML form that has a submit button to take the reader to a web page. The button has some args attached to it in a query string that is read by the processing script triggered by the submit.

But on the Samsung unit I get back a display of my URI string and the error message and nothing more.

It works fine on my laptop and my iPhone, but not on a Samsung 5/6 mobile phone. That is the only place I see the error message:

> 'net err cache miss'

Yes, I've seen a whole lot of discussions on this topic but none seem to apply to my scenario.

Here is the code in the email giving the problem:

```
$htmlcode = "<!DOCTYPE html>".$crlf;
$htmlcode .= "<html lang='en'>".$crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;     charset=UTF-8'>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<head>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<style type='text/css'>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "body{font-size:14px;margin:0%;padding:0%;}" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "</style>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "</head>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<body>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<p>$ans_msg</p>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<form name='thisform'  action='http://jimginer.net/jump_to_nascar_currweek.php?poolid=$poolid&weekno=$weekno' method='POST'>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<br><br>";

$htmlcode .= "<p>For Pool: $poolid & Week: $weekno</p>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "<input type='submit' style='margin-left:10%;' name='btn' value='View the Grid'>".$crlf;

$htmlcode .= "</form>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "</body>" . $crlf;

$htmlcode .= "</html>" . $crlf;

$sendmsg = $htmlcode;

mail($to, $subject, $sendmsg, $headers);
```

Comment: Including a `<form>` in an email is *super* unconventional and [most email clients won't support it](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email). I can't say for certain it's causing *that* issue, but it's a possibility. It may help to debug by removing the form an see what happens.

Comment: Just finding out that it is not a conventional thing.  Did not know that since it worked so well for me with an iphone.   Anyway - found out that just using an anchor tag in this particular situation worked like a charm.